# Creating RoR Links within Ajax call in .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have the following ajax call that activates on button click:

```
    $.ajax({

            url: button_action,

            data: {},

            type: "POST",

            dataType: "json",

            success: function( data ) {

                var att = data.attendees

                var attendee_list = "";

                for (i = 0; i < data.attendees.length; i++) {
                    if ( i != att.length-1) {
                        attendee_list += att[i].first_name + " " + att[i].last_name + ", ";
                    }       else {
                        attendee_list += att[i].first_name + " " + att[i].last_name 
                    }
                }

                att_array.innerHTML = attendee_list;
            }, . . . 

        });
```

Now, we see that I'm getting a list of event attendees back from the server in `data.attendees`. I'm able to get the first and last name of each attendees, and I can just as easily get the id of the attendees with `id = att[i].id`. Instead of just displaying the name of each attendee, I would like to *create a link* to that attendees `show`page using their `id`. Ideally, I would create a variable `full_name = att[i].first_name + " " att[i].last_name`and then create a link like

```
<%#= link_to full_name, user_path(user.id) %>
```

I am aware that this involves taking json or javascript variables and using them in Ruby code, and then outputting Ruby code. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: This is, by design, impossible. The problem is that the Ruby code renders first (since it is server-side) and the JavaScript renders after it. So you can't really 'inject' json in a Ruby method because the helper 'link_to' will execute before the javascript is even requested from the server.

Comment: Any idea on how to get create a link using javascript then?

Comment: writing an answer now

Comment: Thanks man! I really appreciate your help. This has been stumping me for a while and I'm in dire need of some expert advice.

Comment: You can read this about Ujs - https://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/ . It's kind of old, but the principles are the same. If you want to render stuff dynamically using only RoR, Ujs is the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your are doing it, with a simple AJAX request, is impossible (by design). The problem is that the Ruby code renders first (since it is server-side) and the JavaScript renders after it. So you can't really 'inject' json in a Ruby method because the helper `link_to` will execute before the JavaScript is even requested from the server.

What you would like to have it is using unobtrusive JavaScript (UJs). It is done by putting `:remote => true` on your link. After doing so, the request will go to the server-side method put in your link (`attendees`). Server side, you need to have a `respond_to` block:

```
def attendees
  @attendees = Attendee.all #I'm making this up for the example
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end        
end
```

Then, you need a `.js.erb` file named after the action, i.e `attendees.js.erb`. It will be called when the server-side gets executed. You will receive an array of items. You need a partial that is going to iterate through them. Here is how you are going to do it. In `attendees.js.erb`

```
('.attendee-list-container').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'attendees_list', :locals => { :attendees => @attendees }) %>");
```

And finally, in your `_attendees_list.html.erb`, you can iterate and create links.

```
#in HAML:
-attendees.each do |attendee|
  =link_to "#{attendee.first_name + ' ' + attendee_last_name}" , attendee
```

That's it.